# Match Polish letters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, unicode

I am quite confused about the following cases, in Mathematica 9.0.1.0:

```
LetterQ["ł"]

StringMatchQ["ł", WordCharacter ..]
```

The first case gives `True`. The second gives `False`.
Documentation states that WordCharacter match anything for which LetterQ is true.

Comment: With `v11.3.0` on my Mac both expressions evaluate to `True`

Comment: Ah, so this must be a bug then, in the older version, I suppose.

Comment: I guess you could say they *polished* `StringMatchQ` in newer versions.